# Launch Sublime Text via command-line and return

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, zsh

I'm using sublime text 2 on Mac OS at work and on Ubuntu 14.04 at home.

At work, when I use 'subl .' on the command line, it open the folder I'm in in Sublime, then return so I can type other commands.

At home, when I 'subl .', it open the files too. But it don't return, and my console is used to pass me messages from sublime running.

I'm missing something there, I can't find how to do this simple configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about launching `subl` as a background process with `&`?

```
subl . &
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another problem, allready treated there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165426/sublime-text-on-ubuntu-14-04-keeps-attempting-to-remove-it Ubuntu 14.04 seems to be responsible here.

Answer (score 0):

Use following way

```
subl . &
```

This is [unix background command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait)